# Python write to variable and read from it

Tags: python, pdf

I wrote the following Python code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
from io import BytesIO

output_pdf = PdfFileWriter()
tmp = BytesIO()

def orderSecondFile(file):
    with open(file, 'rb') as readfile:
            input_pdf = PdfFileReader(readfile)
            total_pages = input_pdf.getNumPages()
            for page in range(total_pages - 1, -1, -1):
                output_pdf.addPage(input_pdf.getPage(page))
                output_pdf.write(tmp)
            tmp.seek(0)
            return tmp.getvalue()
sec_file=orderSecondFile("path to file")
f= open(sec_file,'rb')
```

when I run `f= open(sec_file,'rb')` it turns the following error: **utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c in position 696: invalid start byte**
How can I solve it?
I want to open sec_file and manipulate it for example merging it with another pdf file.
Thank you for your time

Comment: It's not clear what `orderSecondFile` is even returning; `tmp` is never defined, nor is `output_pdf` for that matter.

Comment: What is `tmp`? It looks like the conversion between the contents of `tmp` to a string failed due to `tmp` containing invalid UTF8.

Answer (score 0):

```
#file.txt is a filepath
document = open('file.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
```

You just needed to add a comma, with the way you wish to open it:

(`w` for write, `r` for read, `a` for append and `b` for bytes; which can be concatenated with the rest)

and then type `encoding='utf-8'`

The `encoding='utf-8'` means that it will be opened in UTF-8, which it isn't by default and presumably some of the bytes in your file are encoded in UTF-8.

I ran into this problem a while ago.

**Happy coding!**

Comment: Unfortunately the problem has not been resolved and even if I use the suggested code "open('file.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')"  it continues to give the same error: utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c in position 696: invalid start byte. If I use: open('file.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8').